# Can't boot Windows 10 anymore

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu on an existing Windows 10, dual boot was fine for some months. Now I try again and it doesn't work anymore. grub-update doesn't find any OS besides Ubuntu. Using boot-repair from a USB-Stick finds the EFI partition on nvmen1p1, but booting from that results in

```
error: can't find command 'parttool'.
error: can't find command 'drivemap'.
error: invalid EFI file path.
```

nvmen1p2, where the real Windows 10 is located, is not found, even from the USB stick.

`sudo os-probe` on regular Ubuntu finds nothing.

Here is the pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/H54w8bCwws/

Any advice?

Comment: You have mixed BIOS & UEFI. Your Windows is in the old BIOS/MBR configuration. Microsoft has required  vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode with gpt partitioning since 2012. So most hardware now is UEFI. But then you orginally installed Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. It looks like you have reinstalled grub in BIOS boot mode, but have boot flag on 3  partitions. It should only have boot flag on sda1, the Windows boot partition. Grub does not use boot flag. Also grub only boots working WIndows. You may have to temporarily reinstall Windows boot loader, fix Windows or turn off fast start up.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the boot flags. How do I reinstall the Windows boot loader or fix Windows? I believe fast startup is already off.

Comment: Is it possible to convert Windows to GPT/UEFI without loosing it?

Comment: I have seen several sites/posts where users try converting. But almost all have come back and posted they had to do a new clean install. So have good backups. The partitioning with WIndows is totally different between UEFI/gpt & BIOS/MBR. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations & 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Add it manualy in your `grub.cfg`. Add

> menuentry "Windows 10" --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option
> 'osprober-efi-F024-2799' {
> insmod part_gpt
> insmod fat
> if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
> search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  F024-2799
> else
> search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root F024-2799
> fi
> chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
> }

below the line `### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober_proxy ###`. It can be another number than 30, but 30 is the most common number for os-prober.
Remember that after an `sudo update-grub` you will have to do this again. And also make backup first.
If it works please accept the answer. If it doesn't, report back and we will look for other options.

Comment: That fails with:
```
error: no such device: F024-2799.
error: file `/DEFI?Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found.
```

Comment: Take a look at:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-performance/troubleshooting-windows-8-and-10-failure-to-start/bcf8503c-1b39-4827-9734-a64fef725d0f

Answer (score 0):

I got it working again. Rough steps:

1. Add small GUID partition at the beginning of the disk.
2. Download Windows 10 and install on external hard disk.
3. Run from there and repair (had to go down to the command line and follow some advice I found elsewhere, can't remember).
4. Now I can switch between Windows and Ubuntu in